# "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect." -- bad Content-Type

Tags: jax-rs

While sending some test requests to a JAX-RS REST server, I got back a

```
400 - Bad Request
The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

The request was

```
PUT http://localhost:8080/some/url
Content-Type: text-plain
foo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Content-Type: text-plain
```

is a typo and a bad MIME type. It should be

```
Content-type: text/plain
```

This was a bit of a head-scratcher for a while.