# HTTP calls in same wireless network glassfish

Tags: android, http, glassfish-4

I have an endpoint which is available at following url: http://localhost:18080/app/register (via POST request). I want to make calls to this endpoint from my Android device, which is in the same Wireless network (the IP for the laptop running the server is 172.16.xx.xx). When I am making my request from the laptop (server) to this endpoint:  http://172.16.xx.xx:18080/app/register, everything works fine.

When I am making the POST request from my Android device to the same endpoint, I get back a 400 Bad Request with message "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect". I checked the URL, I checked the JSON, I made the request with exactly the same body via curl from my laptop and everything looks fine.

Has someone experience this problem before? I don't know where I should start from with my investigation. I am deploying my application on Glassfish 4.1.2

Comment: Check the server logs. Add your code. Try something other than GlassFish

Comment: the server log doesn't say anything about my call. what code to add? I think the problem is somewhere that I am trying to do my calls in the same wireless network. maybe I should check somewhere, but I don't know where :)

Comment: The fact that you don't get "server unreachable" means you're fine in the same network. Please add the code that generates the error... If that is the client code, then that

Comment: At a bit of a guess, I would think your Android request is not correct. When you make the request from your laptop, are you using an Android emulator to run the same code as on your device or using something like Postman or Insomnia to create the POST request?

Comment: [See this answer for an example of a simple typo which could cause this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27929826/212224)

Comment: @Mike I am making exactly the same request with Postman and it works fine... maybe is my Android request that is wrong, I checked the URLs, the request body with the debugger and everything looks fine :( ... I will further investigate into this.